# How to open EF.IO_CONFIG file on Smartcard

Tags: smartcard, contactless-smartcard

I am trying to read the content of EF.IO_CONFIG file on my CIPURSE SmartCard. While there is no literature on the web on how can I do that, I am trying my luck with asking it here.

Is that even possible ?  If yes, what software should I use ? 
I have a DUALi reader and the CIPURSE card.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the conditions required to interact with this file (SMR,ART) using the GET_FILE_ATTRIBUTES command (refer to the CIPURSE Operation and Interface Specification).

Beware that for *certain CIPURSE cards* this file access *might be* additionally restricted (contact your card supplier for the data sheet, as far as I know the EF.IO_CONFIG is not standardized by OSPT).